# In Redis, how do I get subscribe to all new key values?

Tags: redis

In Redis, when I want to subscribe to a particular key I can do something like this:

```
SUBSCRIBE __keyspace@0__:test:foo
```

Now, whenever `test:foo` is updated I receive a notification:

```
2) "__keyspace@0__:test:foo"
3) "set"
```

However, this only tells me *that* `test:foo` has been `set`, but not the new value. How can I subscribe to any new values, not just the commands that were run on them? Note that the values are being set, not `PUBLISH`ed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to publish custom messages in a custom channel using regular [*pubsub*](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub). There's no other way.

Comment: Put differently, keyspace notifications **do not** include the keys' values.

Comment: Is there some kind of industry-standard tool / plugin that can be used to automatically subscribe me to updated values?

Comment: @quant No. It's your app layer the responsible of publishing these messages :(

Comment: @Matías Can you please elaborate on your answer? How might the custom message get the updated value?

Comment: @Matthew You need to publish your own message and put on it every info you might require to communicate to subscribers.